# Стоит ли использовать альтернативные токены в современном коде?

Tags: c++

Например, вместо `!` -- `not`, вместо `&&` -- `and`. Таким образом увеличивается читаемость кода, как в питоне.

Comment: Гм. С моей точки зрения - это резко ухудшает читаемость кода...

Comment: @Harry это же английские слова вместо случайных символов; `if (not found)` против `if (!found)`

Comment: А она точно увеличивается, читаемость-то?

Comment: @ДжонниКэтсвилл `if (found and not empty)` против `if (found && !empty)`; первое можно читать как английский текст в отличие от второго

Comment: В какм-нибуть C++29 их может и выпилят, как например тройные знаки.

Comment: Ну вот прямо сейчас, смотря на ваш пример, по моим субъективным ощущениям, в коде `found and not empty` мне понадобилось некоторое дополнительное время, чтобы отличить имена переменных от логических операторов, в то время как здесь `found && !empt` сразу видно где переменная, а где логический оператор.

Comment: @ДжонниКэтсвилл так в редакторе будет разная подсветка у них

Comment: Советую закрыть вопрос поскольку холиварная тема. Найдутся и за и против.

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков у них разные цели. Вторые удалили из-за проблем в строковых литералах и комментариях; https://stackoverflow.com/q/27601706.

Comment: @AzizUmarov меня устроит ответ, в котором будут перечислены "за" и "против". У всего есть + и - почти что, единственное правильное решение редко существует

Comment: @srun по частоте использования примерно одинаково нигде не видел. Выпилят их когданибуть и напишут использовать десяток строк макросов кому надо.

Comment: да нет никаких за и против - дело привычки, другое дело, что в С побитовые операции и логические сравнения отличаются, если ввести `and` и т.п. - это должно касаться только логических? сейчас хотя бы логика есть `|` - побитовая `||` - логическая, так что вряд ли такое менять будут, что могут менять в языке, так это излишне длинные или корявые конструкции, а логические операции к ним не относятся

Comment: @Zhihar `bitor` и `and`, и не надо гадать что палочки значат. Понятно, что опытные программисты знают это, но теперь код даже не С++ программист поймёт

Comment: Все эти `bitor` и `and` банально раздувают код, увеличивают его в размерах. Делают строки длиннее, а это ухудшает восприятие, сложнее охватить всю строку разом. Почему бы не пойти дальше и не заменить операторы `=` и `+` операторами `assignment` и `plus`, тогда можно будет писать `z assignment a plus b`. Всё на английском, и не надо гадать, что палочки значат, и нет никаких непонятных крестиков...

Comment: "Это же английские слова" - именно! Наше счастье, что это - не родной для нас язык! Программирование в стиле "если а нет равно б тогда присвоить" - было бы ужасным несчастьем. Вы можете представить математику в духе не "x^2+px+q=0", а "x умножить на x плюс p умножить на x плюс q равно 0"? Порешайте вот так задачки - может, и дойдет...

Comment: Дело не только в читабельности.  На клавиатуре могут не быть клавиш для специальных символов или их ввод может быть затруднен по разным причинам,  или эти клавиши могут быть зарезервированы  для специального использования... Если нет этих проблем, нет причины  воспользоваться альтернативными токенами точно также, как и не причины вместо символа '=' в математике воспользоваться  словом "равно", поскольку одному это слово понятно, другому нет, символ понятен всем и лучше выделяет текст.

Comment: Если не хотите **личных проблем**, не делайте этого

Comment: Еще обязательно надо заменять все `cin >>` и `cout <<` на вызовы функций, чтоб звучало по-английски - что-то вроде `write_to(cout,str)` - так будет удобочитабельнее.... :)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Имеет смысл использовать исключительно текстовые варианты токенов при использовании поддерживающих их операций. Их использование дает следующие преимущества:

- Отсутствие коллизии с этими же токенами, использующимися для других целей, можно отличить побитывый И от ссылки или взятия адреса, а логический И - от rvalue и универсальной ссылки, побитовое НЕ от деструктора. Соответственно можно осуществлять поиск битовых и логических операций, и т.п.
- Снижается количество дефектов, связанных с некорректным использованием `&` вместо `&&` и `|` вместо `||` (или наоборот), двойных `!`.

Еще стоит отметить `&` для взятия адреса - вместо него имеет смысл по возможности использовать `::std::addressof`.

Comment: Не завидую тем, кто будет читать такие программы....

Comment: Дело привычки. SQL и Delphi отлично читается, когда глаз наметан

Comment: @Kromster видимо большинство недовольных альтернативными токенами и проголосовавших за закрытие вопроса делают это по принципу "не читал, но осуждаю". Откровенно говоря, даже о самом существовании альтернативных токенов в С++ известно далеко не всем, не говоря уж сколько-нибудь объемной практике их использования.

Comment: Лично я недоволен тем, что под явной вкусовщиной (ровно такой же, как "скобки - египетские ли Quake?") стоит однобокий ответ, да еще и с зеленой галкой.

Comment: Ну не знаю, сам я начинал с Паскаля, и когда впервые столкнулся с Си, использование простых, коротких, принципиально отличающихся от символьных идентификаторов операторов наподобие `^` и `!` вместо `Xor` и `Not` меня приятно удивило.

Comment: @gbg Что значит "под явной вкусовщиной"? Вкусовщина - это рассуждать о "читабельности" на основе своих субъективных ощущений, причем с большой вероятность полученных за последние пять минут при чтении этого вопроса. А в ответе приведены два конкретных объективных профита от перехода.

Comment: @user7860670 это все личные предпочтения того, кто читает код + притягивание за уши крайне маловероятных вариантов использования типа "найти все битовые отрицания и не перепутать их с деструкторами". 

Более того, все эти хотелки прекрасно решаются автоформатом, без необходимости заставлять некоторую часть команды менять выработанные годами привычки.

Comment: operator&  может быть перегружен для какого то класса в других целях(например для получения указателя на указатель), тогда для взятия адреса придется использовать  std::addressof., и  очень спорный вопрос, стоит ли  воспользоваться  им повсеместно(лично я против).

Comment: А про С++17 это точная инфа? Вроде бы в С++ они и раньше ключевыми словами выделялись. Может вы с С перепутали, там макросы?

Comment: Почему же в стандартной библиотеке очень трудно найти применение этих "преимуществ" ?...

Comment: @srun Кстати да, они же и раньше были зарезервированными идентификаторами.

Comment: @user7860670, сами их используете?

Comment: @avp Использую всегда, за исключением легаси проектов или каких-то сторонних правок, чтобы код там оставался единообразным. И очень доволен.

Comment: @user7860670, в одиночку код ваяете и для личного употребления?

Comment: Свои функции вместо операторов `<<` и `>>` для ввода-вывода пишете?

Comment: @avp Ну отчего же, могу вас заверить, что этот подход успешно опробован на достаточно крупных коммерческих проектах. Благо там было не болото, где никто не хочет "менять выработанные годами привычки".

Comment: @Mikhailo Ну операторы `<<` и `>>` для ввода-вывода же обычно только для совместимости с `ostream`-подобным выводом пишутся.